# Как сделать модель из JSON данных для GridView?

Tags: json, yii2, gridview

Подскажите как можно в Yii2 реализовать dataprovider и передать его в gridview данные я получаю в виде json и есть еще такой момент что поля в нем имеют связи к другим похожим данным состоящие так же из json. В интернете не нашел каких то готовых решений, а изобретать велосипед не хочется.

Comment: Перегнать json в массив и аррейдатапровайдером его? https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/output-data-providers#array-data-provider

Comment: А как сделать связь?

Comment: Может быть из массива забрать айдишники и получить массив моделей через in(1,2,3,), а потом использовать его как обычно с провайдером и связями.

Comment: Мне бы живой реальный рабочий пример увидеть.

Comment: А что увидеть надо? Как json в массив перегнать или как айдишники получить? Как получить модели и отобразить их с помощью gridView есть в документации или можно сгенерировать CRUD и посмотреть там.